# Adb install progress bar

Tags: android, command, adb, line

I'm a beginner at this so just mind me if I ask anything obvious. I'm trying to install an *apk* to my device using `adb install apk.apk` however, the *apk* is around a few hundred MB big and it takes some time. Is there some sort of progress bar that I could implement in the command window to show the progress? I've seen stuff for *adb push/pull* . I'm not sure if it's the same. I'm running this in *Windows 8.1*. I also have an *adb* environment variable set up.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 24):

Well, `adb install apk.apk` is just a glorified shortcut for:

```
adb push apk.apk /data/local/tmp
adb shell pm install /data/local/tmp/apk.apk
adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/apk.apk
```

So if you are so inclined to see the upload progress bar - just `adb push -p` your apk first and then `adb shell pm install` it either manually or with a simple script.

Answer (score 5):

A bit bulky but ADB can become verbose if you ask it to:

```sh
$ adb --help
...
 $ADB_TRACE
     comma-separated list of debug info to log:
     all,adb,sockets,packets,rwx,usb,sync,sysdeps,transport,jdwp
```

For example, if you set `ADB_TRACE=all` before calling `adb push` (e.g. by running `ADB_TRACE=all adb push path/to/app.apk` in a single line, or doing an `export ADB_TRACE=all` in advance), then you'd get something like this:

```
...
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=72
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=72 got=72 535441320000000020fd000000000000 STA2.... ....... [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=51 53454e442b0000002f646174612f6c6f SEND+.../data/lo [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 4441544100000100504b030400000000 DATA....PK...... [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 44415441000001002c7903adab89d6d5 DATA....,y...... [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 4441544100000100e570055c0957c1d5 DATA.....p.\.W.. [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 4441544100000100f94f47fe441a3fa6 DATA.....OG.D.?. [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 44415441000001007bf1fa1b58c33b89 DATA....{...X.;. [truncated]
adb D 01-02 15:41:36 41828 1867505 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=65544 4441544100000100c6d8384d98f7b39d DATA......8M.... [truncated]
...
```

which roughly shows what appears to be 64k block transmissions with timestamps, in real time.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not calling the push/install operation (for example, Android Studio is doing it for you), you can query the push status as follows (bash script):

```
function check_push_progress(){
     local push_to=$1 #path in the device
     local push_from=$2 #path to local file
     local current=0
     local complete=1
     while [ $current -ne $complete ]; do
        current=`adb shell ls -l $push_to | awk '{print $5}'`
        complete=`ls -l $push_from | awk '{print $5}'`
        echo pushed $current bytes, out of $complete bytes, $((100*$current/$complete))%
        sleep 1
    done
}
```