# Is it possible to install APK through adb if the file is on the android device?

Tags: android, macos, adb, macos-sierra

Usually if the apk is on my desktop, I would use `adb install <path>` to get it on my Android device. Somehow I like to know if it is also possible if the apk is on the device. I imagine `adb shell` would be a start, sadly tho, `install <path>` afterward doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999449/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb shell
pm install /location/apk.apk
// if you want to remove the installation package
rm /location/apk.apk
```